# Code not working in Visual Studio 2017 but works in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, breadth-first-search

I am writing a project for my algorithms classes and I need it to work on Visual Studio 2017. Everything works fine when I compile it with g++ through command line, but when I try to start the program through VS 2017 it goes into infinite loop in this funciton (its part of dinic`s max flow algorithm):

```
bool Graph::BFS(int s, int t)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        level[i] = -1;

    level[s] = 0; // Level of source vertex

    list<int> q;
    q.push_back(s);

    vector<Edge>::iterator i;
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); i++)
        {
            Edge &e = *i;
            if (level[e.v] < 0 && e.flow < e.C)
            {
                // Level of current vertex is, level of parent + 1 
                level[e.v] = level[u] + 1;

                q.push_back(e.v);
            }
        }
    }
    // IF we can not reach to the sink we return false else true
    return level[t] < 0 ? false : true;
}
```

in the while loop specificly.

How do I go about fixing it? Did anyone experience such thing before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, bugged code working in on environment but not in another is perfectly common. You haven't provided enough information to diagnose the bug but you are making a lot of array/vector accesses, I expect one of those is going out of bounds.

Comment: @john It is a alorithm form geeks for geeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dinics-algorithm-maximum-flow/

Comment: Can you find an error in it?

Comment: Like @john said you have not provided enough information. for example what are s and t values ? try to use debugger and see what values go into this function because from the link you provided i can see that this is just a function from the middle of the algorithm

Comment: @Paweł I'm not saying the algorithm is wrong, it could easily be that you are feeding bad data to the algorithm. Debugging is tricky without seeing a complete program.

Comment: @Paweł this happens all the time on this site. Someone says their program isn't working and they don't know why, they then post a perfectly correct piece of code and ask for help. Often it turns out the problem was in some part of their code that they didn't think was worth posting.

Comment: @john  geeksforgeeks.org/dinics-algorithm-maximum-flow <- that is the part of my project that is no working, if you scroll down on this page there is a code containing the funcion from my post.  In VS code with g++ it works and in Visual Studio 2017 it doesnt, even if you copy the alogryth 1-1 for the site. I really need it to work, but I cant see any error there :/

Comment: @Paweł You seem to be ignoring what I'm saying. Without a complete program I (nor anyone else) can help. If you want to help yourself, then at least appeciate that the problem may not be in the code you have posted.

Comment: This code from geeks for geeks has its main function as well, it just doesnt work.

Comment: @john I am sure that this is the problem, because when I use the exact same code fro the site with exact main fuction it works on VS code and doesnt work win VS 2017

Comment: @Paweł OK, I'll try the code.

Comment: @Paweł That's a completely incorrect assumption, it's normal for bugged code to work in one place, and not work in another.

Comment: @john I only implemented min() myself and changes includes to : #include <iostream> #include <vector> #include <list>. May this be a problem?

Comment: This code is the worst implementation of an algorithm I have ever seen. Don't they do reviewing on GfG? If you use this code you have a big bag of problems. This is NOT the way to do it. And we all wonder why there are so many problems in the programs. **Start from scratch** and create a good piece of software.

Comment: @john that is why I would really apriciate your help in debuging the code :)

Comment: @rioV8 Could you share a better implementation? Although I can only use basic std libraries, and deffinitely not <graph> :)

Comment: @Paweł Well I agree, it's bugged. Did you try and pass this off as your own code earlier? Are you going to submit code from the internet for your assignment?

Comment: @john This is a big project  and I am allowed to use code form the internet for the maxflow problem. I did not post this as my own code, I was just looking for a solution to my problem

Comment: Learning to program is **not** finding other people to do your work.

Comment: What is the use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. It is **never** used.

Comment: @Paweł OK I've figured out the problem, geeksforgeeks does not have a good reputation, and here is an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geeksforgeeks [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dinics-algorithm-maximum-flow/) from which the above code derives is bugged. The error is in the `Graph::DinicMaxflow` method. The code assumes that in this line

```
int *start = new int[V+1];
```

the `start` array will be initialised to zero, but C++ does not guarantee that. It will be initialised to zero by some compilers and not others. Visual Studio does not initialise this array to zero, but clearly whatever compiler you are using behind VSCode does.

To guarantee zero initialisation, change the above line to this

```
int *start = new int[V+1]{};
```

Comment: Or just use `std::vector<int> start(V+1)`, which does initialize all elements to zero. Generally, code which uses `new[ ]` shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: @MSalters I've just noticed that not only is the original code bugged, and in poor style, it also never frees the allocated memory. Incredible.